# variable declared as uint but accepting negative values instead of throwing errors

Tags: solidity, uint256

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract setget{
    uint x;
    function setnumber(uint _x) public {
        x=_x;
    }
    function getnumber() public view returns(uint){
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. There is no question here. 2. There is no demonstration here of what you are describing (nor the negative value neither the error thrown). 3. If you call the function from the off-chain with a negative value, then it will be converted to `unsigned` in the on-chain side, using 2s-complement. 4. If you call it from the on-chain, then you're likely to get a compilation error, or at least a compilation warning, but in either case - not a runtime exception.

Comment: 5. If you want your code to be displayed properly, then indent it by 4 spaces.

Comment: how to accept only positive values i tried require(_x>0) and assert(_x>0) also...

Comment: Like I said, the value will be converted to `uint`, so you'll need to add this assertion on the caller side, not in this function. Or you can use `int` instead of `uint`, and then `require(_x>0)` will become useful. You'll also need to change `x=_x` to `x=uint(_x)`.

Comment: thank you.. i added it in the function itself and it worked... but if it accepts negative values then what is the main purpose of introducing uint then..

Comment: The purpose is for you to keep the **state variable** `x` as `uint`. If you change it to `int` then it impacts all of the arithmetic operations involving `x` (there aren't any in the code which you posted, but I assume that there are such operations in your real contract).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both, `uint` and `int` are 256-bit long in Solidity, so arbitrary sequence of 256 bits may be interpreted in both ways.  For example, sequence of 256 "ones" is `-1` when interpreted as `int`, and is `115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935` when interpreted as `uint`.

I assume you are passing negative value to your function via Web3 API.  Your Web3 API implementation does not do range check.  It just converts your negative number into a 256-bit sequence and passes it to your smart contract, and smart contract just interprets it as `uint`.

There is no reliable way for smart contract to know whether particular 256-bit sequence passed to it was initially representing `int` or `uint`.  Though, one thing may probably help.  The idea is that positive numbers have the same binary representation for both types, so in case value you got is less than or equals to maximum possible `int` value, then it has never been negative.  So you may add the following line to the beginning of your method:

```
require (_x <= 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF);
```